# how to replicate a table records multiple time on the basis of MonthStart_Date and MonthEnd_date in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

How to replicate a table record multiple time in the same table on the basis of `monthStartDate` and `MonthEndDate`, Suppose i have table that contain one row only along with `monthStartDate`  and `MonthEndDate` . The month start date is `01-Jan-2018` and `MonthendDate` is `31-jan-2018`, Now i want to replicate this one record to 31 time.

Below is the table structure .

tbl_Employee

```
EmployeeID  Name            TeamManagerEmpID    TeamManagerName OpsManagerID    OpsManagerName  Department  FromDate    ToDate
210000      Peter Anderson  110000              Alex Broad      100000          Steve Anderson  BI          01-Jan      31-Jan
210000      Peter Anderson  110001              Smith Jones     100000          Steve Anderson  BI          01-Feb      31-Mar
```

Now i am expecting the below output .

```
MetricDate  EmployeeID  Name            TeamManagerEmpID    TeamManagerName OpsManagerID    OpsManagerName  Department
01-Jan      210000      Peter Anderson  110000              Alex Broad      100000          Steve Anderson  BI
02-Jan      210000      Peter Anderson  110000              Alex Broad      100000          Steve Anderson  BI
03-Jan      210000      Peter Anderson  110000              Alex Broad      100000          Steve Anderson  BI
04-Jan      210000      Peter Anderson  110000              Alex Broad      100000          Steve Anderson  BI
```

could you please help me.

Comment: First change your date's type to an actual date (or month and year separately), working with dates as varchar leads to lots of problems. Then you can use a recursive CTE which adds 1 day each time, from the FromDate to the ToDate.

Comment: could you please provide me a sample code

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define proper DATE datatype for FromDate and ToDate. Then, you should have a separate date table for generating dates between FromDate and ToDate. I have given sample code below for your reference.

```
CREATE TABLE #employee
(
empid int,
empname varchar(30),
empStartDate datetime,
empEndDate datetime);

CREATE TABLE #dimdate
(
datevalue datetime
);

INSERT INTO #employee 
values(1,'venkat','20180101','20180131');

DECLARE @startDate datetime = '20180101'
DECLARE @cutoffDate datetime = '20180131'

INSERT #dimdate(datevalue) 
SELECT d
FROM
(
  SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, @StartDate)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) 
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    -- on my system this would support > 5 million days
    ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
  ) AS x
) AS y;

SELECT [datevalue],e.empid, e.empname, e.empStartDate
FROM #dimDate as d
CROSS JOIN #employee as e
WHERE d.datevalue IN ( select d.datevalue FROM #dimdate WHERE d.datevalue >= e.empStartDate and d.datevalue  <= e.empEndDate) ;
```